# How to use imported HealthKit samples in other classes

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I have imported all the necessary health data into my app, but when I try to use the health variables outside of the class in which I imported them, I keep getting `nil` values.

I have a class with a method that successfully imports the data and a method that successfully prints the data:

```
class HealthData:NSObject {

    var healthData:Double?

    func importData() {
        readMostRecentSample(sampleType!, completion: { (mostRecentSample, error) -> Void in
            self.printData()
        })
    }
    func printData() {
        print(healthData)
    }
}
```

But when I try and do something like this in a new class:

```
class HealthAlgorithm:NSObject {

    var healthData2 = HealthData().healthData

    func printData() {
        print(healthData2)
    }
}
```

And I call that function from the same place I successfully called the original `printData` method:

```
class HealthData:NSObject {

    var healthData:Double?

    func importData() {
        self.printsData()
        HealthAlgorithm().printsData()
    }
    func printsData() {
        print(healthData)
    }
}
```

I've run into issues similar to this, and I realize that the method querying for HealthKit samples completes asynchronously, but I'm a little stumped as to exactly what is happening here.  I think I'm missing something to do with completion handlers, but I'm not sure exactly where to start.

(If you want more complete code, I can include it, but I thought I would save some space by simplifying things.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a healthKit problem.

In all your classes

```
 var healthData:Double?
```

is an instance variable that is automatically initialized with nil. This means in

```
var healthData2 = HealthData().healthData
```

the part

```
HealthData()
```

creates a new instance. So

```
HealthData().healthData
```

is always nil, since you didn't import anything in this instance.

You probably imported into another instance of that class.

More about this: Apples Swift eBook is free.

Answer (score 0):

You're HealthData class should be a singleton object. The recommended Swift singleton pattern is

```
class HealthData:NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = HealthData()
...
}
```

and then access the data from other classes like

```
HealthData.sharedInstance().myfunc()
```